# Changing position property with jQuery doesn't work correctly in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

What should be a few simple lines of jQuery doesn't seem to be working properly in Internet Explorer. Works fine in Firefox. When you scroll within 200px of the bottom of the viewport, the fixed position div should "stick" to the page as you scroll past.

Here is a jsFiddle example of the problem:
[jsFiddle example of fixed position div problem](http://jsfiddle.net/HVhLw/22/)

In Firefox, the example works correctly. When the scroll position is 200 px from the bottom of the document height, the fixed position div becomes position absolute with a Top: property of the height of the page minus the height of the viewport minus the height of the element. In other words, it "sticks" to where it is when you continue scrolling past it.

In Internet explorer, the div simply just stays at the bottom and the jquery if condition is never met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
var till = $('body').height()-800;
```

...rather than

```
var till = $('html').height()-800;
```

I'm guessing the height of the HTML element itself isn't well-defined in IE. You also seem to be using the "this" of the document ready function to grab the window; you should use window instead. Additionally, I think the positioning maths for the "after you've gone past the limit" in your example was a bit wrong.

Also, once you've been through your limit, your div ends up with both a "top" *and* a "bottom" value set in its CSS, which probably confuses the browser. I've added a reset (setting the "bottom" value to "auto" when the "top" value gets set.)

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/HVhLw/32/ ; it seems to work in Firefox and IE for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had posted an older version of my code in the jsFiddle example. It's updated now.

Comment: Here is my updated example with changing $(document) to $('body'). Same problem. Doesn't work in IE7 or IE8. http://jsfiddle.net/HVhLw/23/

Comment: @Chris I think your current jsFiddle won't work because you've wrapped it in a document ready (not needed by jsFiddle when you've selected "onload"). Sorry, this one is probably too much of a moving target for me.

Comment: Removing it causes the example to not run properly.

Comment: @Chris Could we have a bit more detail, please? What does "not run properly" mean, for example?

Comment: I'd imagine without waiting for everything to finish loading the document.height() and window.height() functions are returning wrong numbers. The top: attribute being set is being given the wrong value.

Comment: I should note if you can't run the jsFiddle example for whatever reason, it works fine in FF4 and Chrome with document.ready().

Comment: @Chris This is your fiddle with the document ready sorted out -- seems to do the same thing in IE and Firefox to me, though that might not be what you actually want it to do. (You were assigning "windw" from "this", which is actually the document, not the window, in the document ready function.) http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/KhNAs/5/

Comment: Hmm. I get completely different behavior on FF4 between your fiddle and http://jsfiddle.net/HVhLw/23/

Comment: When you scroll all the way to the bottom on my fiddle, it sticks to its position as you scroll past. When I do it in your example, the div disappears.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Ok, thanks! I updated your fiddle with the working script. (Works in IE) http://jsfiddle.net/KhNAs/8/

Comment: I've updated my answer with a few more points, and a jsFiddle that might work for you.

Comment: @Chris let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2494/discussion-between-matt-gibson-and-chris)

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and IE8 are unpredictable with fixed positioning unless your declare a sensible !DOCTYPE (not sure about IE9, don't own any Win7 machines). I always use XHTML/1.0 Transitional for everything but I think it should also work properly if you declare HTML/4.01 as well.

It's also worth noting that using XHTML fixes IE's annoying habit of treating `text-align: center;` as if it were `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;` and completely ignoring `margin: auto;` declarations.

Don't forget to [validate you markup](http://validator.w3.org/).

e.g.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>

<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>

  <head>
    ...
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle example in my OP with a Doctype. It didn't make a difference, when you run the example.

Comment: The jsFiddle example validates XHTML transitional now. Same problem.